# Find Method references with parameters

Tags: c#, roslyn

Roslyn - I need to find the method references and I have the below code for it.
But the problem is When I have two methods with same name.

E.g.

**Method 1:**

```
public string GetName(string id)
{
}

public string GetName()
{
}
```

Here I have two methods with the same name "GetName" my code is finding the first method (FirstOrDefault is also a reason) but Is there any way to find method reference along with argument list?

**Code:**

```
public static async Task<List<ReferenceLocation>> FindMethodReferences(string solutionPath, string methodName)//*Here methodName is "GetName"*
{
    var msWorkspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
    ISymbol methodSymbol = null;
    bool found = false;    
    var solution = await msWorkspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath);
    foreach (var project in solution.Projects)
    {
        foreach (var document in project.Documents)
        {
            var model = await document.GetSemanticModelAsync();
            var methodInvocation = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync();
            InvocationExpressionSyntax node = null;
            try
            {
                ***//Is there any condition I should add here to find the method references with arg list*** 
                node = methodInvocation.DescendantNodes()
                    .OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>().FirstOrDefault(x => ((MemberAccessExpressionSyntax)x.Expression).Name.ToString() == methodName); 

                if (node == null)
                    continue;
            }
            catch
            {
                continue;
            }

            methodSymbol = model.GetSymbolInfo(node).Symbol;
            found = true;
            break;
        }

        if (found) break;
    }

    return SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync(methodSymbol, solution).Result.SelectMany(item => item.Locations).ToList();
}
```

Comment: what happens if you swap the declaration of the two functions? Place the method with args above the method which has no args while defining them in the class file

Comment: Swapping may not work for all of my scenarios. I want to find a method by method name along with argument (at least by argument's data type).

Comment: Do you know where exactly those `GetName` methods are declared? If yes, I think it'd be easier to get a symbol for their parent class first, then find the required method among its members, and finally use `SymbolFinder` to lookup references in the solution.

Comment: Thank you so much Andrey. I know where the `GetName` method is declared so I got that class declaration using `ClassDeclarationSyntax` and using that I got its `Members` and used `GetDeclaredSymbol` to get `ISymbol` and got the references using `SymbolFinder`.